# How to access config variables in exec_command()s?

Tags: python, waf

I have a configuration function in my wscript:

```py
def configure(ctx):
  ctx.env.V1 = 123

def build(ctx):
    def myfun(task):
        return task.exec_command('echo VAR=${V1}')
    ctx.exec_command('echo VAR=${V1}')
    ctx.add_post_fun(myfun)
```

But in build and in myfun (both) `V1` is not available (it's substituted to an empty string). I can store and load my own `ConfigSet`. I know that `V1` is available in rule, but it seems it is not available in `exec_command()`.

What is the convenient way to do it? To access my config vars in `exec_command()` in `build()` body and in pre-/post- commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs for `waflib.Context.Context.exec_command()`](https://waf.io/apidocs/Context.html#waflib.Context.Context.exec_command) specify it as a thin wrapper around either [`waflib.Utils.run_prefork_process()`](https://waf.io/apidocs/_modules/waflib/Utils.html#run_prefork_process) or [`waflib.Utils.run_regular_process()`](https://waf.io/apidocs/_modules/waflib/Utils.html#run_regular_process), which is a thin wrapper over `subprocess.Popen(**kwargs).communicate()`.

Both of these let you set `env=` as a keyword argument, though it needs to have only values which can actually be stored in the environment (which integers, like your `123`, cannot).

Thus:

```
env_safe_dict = dict(os.environ) # start with parent environment
for k, v in ctx.env:             # add things from context environment
  env_safe_dict[k] = str(v)      # ...after converting them to strings
ctx.exec_command('echo VAR=${V1}', env=env_safe_dict)
```

Comment: It is not cross-platform, due to `$`? In Windows it must be `%...%` ?

Comment: Yes, but that's a problem with the command you're running, not with how the variable gets passed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `v1 = task.env.V1` in your task to build your command. And use python to be portable : `print(f"VAR = {v1}")`